# How do I get the top 4 results of a column in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm not very experienced in mySQL, but

I have a SQL query table where I need to return:

```
Salary_amount_1
Salary_amount_2
Salary_amount_3
Salary_amount_4

(not relevant below)
Salary_Date_1
Salary_Date_2
Salary_Date_3
Salary_Date_4
```

I've got 4 seperate columns for each salary amount to select into in the destination table we're inserting into, and a column called `Salary` with 15+ different amounts in the source table we're selecting from, but **how do I specifically select the first salary for column 1, second for column two, third for three and fourth salary for column four?**
Thanks in advance

What I have tried:

This is what I have (and isn't working for me yet)

```
Select 
  ID,
  Bank Name,
  UserName,
  min(details_Credit) as Salary_Amount_1,
  max(details_Credit) as Salary_Amount_2,
  Case 
    when details_Credit = min(details_Credit)
         and details_Credit > min(details_Credit)
  end Salary_Amount_3,
  ????? as Salary_Amount_4,
```

any help would be appreciated. thank you

Sample Data:

```
Salary| SalaryDate| UserName| BankName
=====================================
1000  |2013-05-23 |MikeRoss |NetBank
1500  |2013-06-23 |MikeRoss |NetBank
2000  |2013-07-22 |MikeRoss |NetBank
1000  |2013-08-15 |MikeRoss |NetBank
```

Desired Results:

```
 Username|Bank|Salary1|Salary2|Salary3|Salary4|Date1|Date2|Date3|Date4
MikeRoss|Netbank|1000|1500|2000|1000|2013-05-23| 2013-06-23| 2013-06-22| 2013-08-15
```

Comment: ORDER BY sal DESC LIMIT 4?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I've  added the sample data and desired results @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Left Join instead to resolve this incase anyone is wondering. i.e

```
left join DB.Table_Name as a1 on a1.ID=a.ID and a1.TransactionDate=a0.maxDate 
left join DB.Table_Name as a2 on a2.ID=a1.ID and a2.TransactionDate<a1.TransactionDate
left join DB.Table_Name as a3 on a3.ID=a2.ID and a3.TransactionDate<a2.TransactionDate
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like this:

```
Select ID, Bank Name, UserName, Salary_amount_1 from yourTable
order by Salary_amount_1 limit 1

Union

Select ID, Bank Name, UserName, Salary_amount_2 from yourTable
order by Salary_amount_2 limit 1,1

Union

Select ID, Bank Name, UserName, Salary_amount_3 from yourTable
order by Salary_amount_3 limit 2,1

Union

Select ID, Bank Name, UserName, Salary_amount_4 from yourTable
order by Salary_amount_4 limit 3,1
```

This will perform 4 queries, each returning one of your desired results.
`limit offset, rowcount` will take the first `rowcount` rows **after** skipping `offset` rows.

That said, I strongly advice you to check the structure of your table.